# Converter Currency String para FloatValue

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

blz? Como posso converter um valor currency string (pt-br) para um float value no javascript.

"10.000,50"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passos:

- remover os pontos: `.split('.').join('')`
- mudar virgula para ponto: `.split(',').join('.')`
- converter em float: `Number('string');`

Para fazer numa linha só seria:

```
Number("10.000,50".split('.').join('').split(',').join('.'));
```

Em função:

```
function toFloat(str) {
    if (typeof str == 'number') return str;
    return Number(str.split('.').join('').split(',').join('.'));
}

var testes = ['10.000,50', '105,45', '1.000.005,70'];
console.log(JSON.stringify(testes.map(toFloat))); // [10000.5,105.45,1000005.7]
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/67Lmhhe1/

Comment: Valeu, obrigado funcionou!